# Bluetooth speaker cuts out when no audio is being played

Tags: windows-8, audio, windows-8.1, bluetooth, speakers

Windows 8.1

Bose Soundlink Mini

---

I have a Bose soundlink Mini paired with my Windows 8.1 computer. It works great for music, but if no sound is played for a few seconds then the speaker turns off it's sound. Then when audio is played again it takes a second or two for the audio to turn back on so the the beginning of the audio is cut off or if it's something short like an interaction sound it just isn't heard at all.

Is this something that can be fixed through Windows settings?

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to network properties page and try disabling the bluetooth adapter and enable it again. If required, you can also try uninstalling the bluetooth adapter from device manager window and reinstall it again and check the audio output.

Comment: I don't see anything about bluetooth in Control Panel > Network and Internet

Comment: Also `PC Settings > PC and devices > Bluetooth` has no real settings available. I don't know what or where "Network Properties" is.